# Convert Categorical values to custom number in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have a pandas dataframe, in which I have categorical values along with numerical ones.
Now instead of getting binary data for categorical data, I want to customize it.

Suppose if I have values like `high` and `low`. pandas is giving `low = 1`, and `high = 0`, which I don't want.

For Example :

```
df_bin=pd.get_dummies(global_df[['CATEGORY','IMPACT']])
```

now event category has values past and the above operation gives past as 1 not 0

so, how can I make it 0

Another column is area having values sales, advertisement
Now for these values, I want to give a custom number

Comment: "I want to customize it". Ok, and we're supposed to do what? You didn't explain anything.

Comment: Please provide more information about your issue. Also, consider including a small sample of your data and your desired results.

Comment: the answer below works? please acccept the answer to let others know it works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
new_label = {"cat_column": {"low": 1, "high": 0}}
df.replace(new_label , inplace = True)
```

To do custom label encoding, create the dict of mappings and use `replace()` to replace your categorical values with numerical ones. You can vary your numerical value depending on your preference.

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: JayPeerchi - Thank you, but not sure why the result became nonetype instead of dataframe

Comment: because it includes `inplace = True`, the dataframe is modified in place, which means it will return nothing  if you don't want, you can do like this `new_df = df.replace(new_label)`

Comment: Thanks alot, you saved my day, I am new to this data science, but I have a task to do linear regression. As one of my data science teammate is having some other majors to do

Comment: you're welcome 